# Access 2010 Dynamically Add textboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hello I am trying to create a Form in Access 2010 with dynamic controls.

On the form there is a list of textboxes for entering information.
However I would like the ability to click a button to dynamically add more textboxes to the form on request. (This is because I am not confident with a set number of text boxes as the information entered at one time could vary)

The problem is that digging around it seems the only way to add controls to a form is to open the form in design mode and add the controls, and when design mode is closed the user is prompted with a dialog asking them to save the changes made in design mode before the form can be reopened in normal mode.

Is there any way to solve this problem or would a workaround be needed (like a large number of hidden textboxes already present in the form? )

Comment: Any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

"...like a large number of hidden textboxes already present in the form..." -- I don't consider that a work-around.  It's your best solution.

It does require the form to be opened for design, but VBA does facilitate these in-use changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds strange...Controls for what ? Do you also plan to add fields to your db on the fly ?  I hope not because then you have a serious design problem.
Otherwise, with the few details you provide, I would think the way to go is very simple: use a "continuous" subform like explained [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx).

Comment: Not so strange.  One typical use is entering search criteria.  For that particular use, I think a subform would be difficult.